# Listview inside a ViewPager with SlidingTabLayout - Height problems

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a Fragment in which I have hosted a ViewPager with TabLayout, the contents of the ViewPager is a Fragment which contains a ListView.

I am aware that my ViewPager is not able to use wrap_content, the height at the start is not getting calculated.

So I did this:

```
 @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;

        final View tab = getChildAt(0);
        if (tab == null) {
            return;
        }

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        if (wrapHeight) {
            // Keep the current measured width.
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        Fragment fragment = ((Fragment) getAdapter().instantiateItem(this, getCurrentItem()));
        heightMeasureSpec = getMeasureExactly(fragment.getView(), widthMeasureSpec);

        //Log.i(Constants.TAG, "item :" + getCurrentItem() + "|height" + heightMeasureSpec);
        // super has to be called again so the new specs are treated as
        // exact measurements.
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    int getMeasureExactly(View child, int widthMeasureSpec) {
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int height = calculateHeight ((ListView)child.findViewById(R.id.list)); //getMeasuredHeight();

        System.out.println("Height is: "+height);
        return MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height , MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }


    private int calculateHeight(ListView list) {

        int height = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            View childView = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, list);
            childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            height+= childView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        //dividers height
      //  height += list.getDividerHeight() * 11; //list.getCount();

        return height;

    }
```

I am getting a List with 10 rows to populate but only 9 are visible, one moves out of the view.

The question here is how can I exactly measure a list row height and add it upto 10 items.

This question has plagued stackoverflow but there seems to be no concrete solution. In particular for a ListView child.  As I can get it to work with a TableLayout.

I am also aware of the memory and scroll constriants of doing this, but this is by design and there is not much I can do about it.

The gist of the above code is to pass the height of one row of list and then multiply it with 10 (Because I only want 10 rows in my list + the divider height)

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you tried multiplying by 11?

Comment: Yes, but that defies logic - isn't very logical and may produce unpredictable result. ALso that would give me an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, if I put that in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In XML file, put in list view option

```
android:layout_weight="0.92"
```